# How to show a block on specific pages using the Node ID instead of an URL?

Tags: 7, blocks

Using the "Show block on specific pages" on a block configure field, is it possible to use the Node ID in lieui of URL.

I.E.

`412` instead of `about/contact-us/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want use the node id you can use node/[id].
Example: node/1

It will works even you are using a path alias, because that route is allways avaiable for any node.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to consider using "[Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)", then there is a solution for this question, as further explained below.

## Part 1: Rules block visibility

Have a look at the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless:
>
> - Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
> - Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
> - What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) intercept the node id of the current page, i.e. if it is **YES** or **NO** (a boolean, right?) the node with `nid = 412` (as in your question).

## Part 2: Create an appropriate Rules Component

The [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module doesn't have a lot of documentation, except in the [README.txt](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n24) that comes with this module. Here is what the crucial part of it is (to get the idea):

> Configuration is done on a per-block basis. To control a block
>   visibility using a rule component, go to the block settings page,
>   scroll down to the "Rules" tab, and select the Rules component that
>   you want to use.
>
> Notice that to be able to be used by this module, a Rules component
>   *must* be constructed in a very specific way. See the [next section](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/rules_block_visibility/tree/README.txt#n36) for
>   more information.

This module comes with 2 sample Rules Components, that should help to understand the concept behind it.

By looking at these samples, I was able to create another Rules Component which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_show_block_only_for_nid_412" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block only for nid 412",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false },
      "node" : { "label" : "Node", "type" : "node" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "node:nid" ], "value" : "412" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

You should be able to import this rule in your own environment.

What this Rules Component does is "only" return a boolean (**1** or **0**), based on the condition if the node's nid is YES or NO equal to `412`.

With that, we're coming close to an actual answer to your question.

## Part 3:

Head over to the "Block" settings for the block you want to only show for the node with `nid = 412`. At the bottom of it's settings, within the typical "Visibility settings", there is now (after you enabled the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module as in Part 1) an extra tab labeled "*Rules*". Using that tab will allow you to select a "Rules Component" that will do what's documented below that selection list field, ie: "***Show this block only if the selected rule returns a positive value. Important: to be listed here, a block visibility rule must have specific parameters and return values.***".

And guess what, in my case I just selected my Rules Component from Part 2

**Note**: it doesn't matter what type of block it is (created by a view, or something else), it works in all cases.